# quick sort, first sort works, parameters for recursive calls don't

Tags: python, quicksort

I wanted to write my own quick sort (i am a beginning programer, i am a aware that i can look that up on the web, the point was for me to get better given a loose description)

It sorts on the first iteration, but unfortunately i cannot get the parameters right for the recursive calls. I think i need 2 recursive calls, one for the left side and one for the right side of the new place of my pivot element.

I know that quick sort can be done better with a better choice of pivot, i just chose the first element of my list.

```
def qt(alist,l,r):
    if l != r:
        x=l+1
        run=l+1
        while run<r:            
            if alist[l]>alist[run]:
                alist[x],alist[run]=alist[run],alist[x]
                x=x+1
                run=run+1

            else :
                run=run+1
        alist[x],alist[l]=alist[l],alist[x]
        #qt(alist,0,x-1)
        #qt(alist,x+1,r)

clist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20,104,3,5,123,423423,9]
l=0
r=len(clist)
qt(clist,l,r)
print clist
```

Comment: Your first sublist should start from `l`, not from 0. I.e. qt(alist, l, x-1) I/o qt(alist, 0, x-1)

Comment: you mean in the recursive call ? ok but then i have to reassign L, don't i ?

Comment: your while loop should be `run<=r` since `r==len(clist-1)`. you should be swapping with `x-1` not `x` and your recursive calls should reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to rename some things for clarity (and I suggest you do so as well):

```
def quickSort(aList, l, r):
    if l < r:
        swap = l
        run = l
        pivot = aList[r]
        while run < r:            
            if pivot >= aList[run]:
                aList[swap],aList[run]=aList[run],aList[swap]
                swap += 1
            run += 1

        aList[swap], aList[r] = aList[r], aList[swap]
        quickSort(aList, l, swap-1)
        quickSort(aList, swap+1, r)
```

Your `swap` value (a.k.a `x`) should probably be inclusive; although if you wished to write an exclusive (left, right] you could, however, it would just go against the grain of the generally accepted [left, right] or [left, right).

**Try it:** https://repl.it/BVTx/1

Answer (score 1):

Your subscripts are, indeed, off.  You have to keep them consistent with the 0-based indexing of Python.  Repairing this will fix your infinite recursion *if* you combine it with a 'less than' check at the start.

Also, there's a slight error in your logic; your value of x can run out of bounds.  Here's my update of your code to fix those first problems; I'll leave the internal logic to you, with the help of standard debugging print statements.  Just before the failure point, we get subscripts of l=13, x=r=15.

```
def qt(alist, l, r):
    print "ENTER", alist, l, r
    if l < r:
        x = l+1
        for run in range(l+1, r):
            if alist[l] > alist[run]:
                alist[x], alist[run] = alist[run], alist[x]
                x += 1

        print "subscripts", l, x, r
        alist[x], alist[l] = alist[l], alist[x]
        qt(alist, l, x-1)
        qt(alist, x+1, r)
    print "LEAVE", alist, l, r

clist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20,104,3,5,123,423423,9]
l=0
r=len(clist)
qt(clist,l,r)
print clist
```